# Downloading many web pages with PHP curl

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I'm building a PHP application which has a database containing approximately 140 URLs.

The goal is to download a copy of the contents of these web pages.

I've already written code which reads the URL's from my database then uses [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to grab a copy of the page. It then gets everything between `<body> </body>`, and writes it to a file. It also takes into account redirects, e.g. if I go to a URL and the response code is 302, it will follow the appropriate link. So far so good.

This all works OK for a number of URLs (maybe 20 or so) but then my script times out due to the `max_execution_time` being set to 30 seconds. I don't want to override or increase this, as I feel that's a poor solution.

I've thought of two workarounds but would like to know if these are a good/bad approach, or if there are better ways.

The first approach is to use a `LIMIT` on the database query such that it splits the task up into 20 rows at a time (i.e. run the script 7 separate times, if there were 140 rows). I understand from this approach it still needs to call the script, download.php, 7 separate times so would need to pass in the LIMIT figures.

The second is to have a script where I pass in the ID of each individual database record I want the URL for (e.g. `download.php?id=2`) and then do multiple Ajax requests to them (`download.php?id=2, download.php?id=3, download.php?id=4` etc). Based on `$_GET['id']` it could do a query to find the URL in the database etc. In theory I'd be doing 140 separate requests as it's a 1 request per URL set up.

I've read some other posts which have pointed to queueing systems, but these are beyond my knowledge. If this is the best way then is there a particular system which is worth taking a look at?

### Edit

There are 140 URLs at the moment, and this is likely to increase over time. So I'm looking for a solution that will scale without hitting any timeout limits.

Comment: Changing max_execution_time is probably the best solution, because you honestly have no idea how long its going to take to grab 140 pages, or if the server is going to lag up and make some requests take longer than others.

Comment: It's not a poor solution to extend the timeout. Use [`set_time_limit(30)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on each step of the loop (or whatever is sensible for a single page). It's a reasonable thing to say that "I'll allow X seconds per cURL call".

Comment: i would go with the ajax call approach. so you can just grab all the records on the database, iterate over it sending the ajax call and then report something when it's complete. the script receiving the call (and making the work) could report back and say something like: "X out of X completed, Y with errors"

Comment: I would go for the third option: Call the script from the command line. I don't know how often you plan to do this, but setting up a line in cron is not that difficult and then you can run your script periodically and for as long as you like.

Comment: either CLI or GUI, the question remains, wich one is more effective way of doing it? Send the request one by one and wait for each one to finish or send all at once (or in batchs) and wait them to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont agree with your logic , if the script is running OK and it needs more time to finish, just give it more time it is not a poor solution.What you are suggesting makes things more complicated and will not scale well if your urls increase.

I would suggest moving your script to the command line where there is no time limit and not using the browser to execute it.

Comment: completly the opposite, increasing the timeout will not escalate when the list goes bigger. you can't just increase the timeout indefinetively. the ajax call will separate and isolate each process into a separate thread so he can have multiple results (success/failure) without having to rerun everything from scratch.

Comment: That is not what i suggested, i said to move to the command line where there is no time limit at all . An equivelant of set_time_limit(0);

Comment: you can't keep command line open indefinitively either, you don't know if the list will go as big as 10.000 or stay the same.

Comment: I've just added a clarification that the list of URL's is likely to increase (over 140). My thinking behind the ajax requests is as @LordNeo has said - it is essentially doing a process that on its own takes 1 - 2 seconds, in batches, so unlikely to hit a timeout/execution time limit.

Comment: If the OP is not familiar with php-cli he can take the ajax route.But if the script logic is sound , error handling, proper termination , no memory leaking etc you can keep it running as long as you like until it gets the job done. Also i have found out that using cli takes care of many little stuff like the execution time and also has access to function not available throught apache that can speed up this kind of tasks e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

Comment: how could he download more than 1 website at a time? not sequentially, but parallel.

Comment: By either forking the script with http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php and providing each fork with a batch of urls to download or much much simpler using the multi_curl function http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: I agree with both approaches - cli and ajax. I think in this instance the cli one is easier because I plan to run this overnight every single day. So providing there are no timeout issues when running it through the cli, I can cron the script to start at night then leave it. I wasn't aware that it would not time out if done via command line.

Comment: Just remember to go slow as to not cause any issues with  the remote server you are accessing and read up on the differences at http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Answer (score 1):

When you have an unknown list wich will take an unknown amount of time asynchronous calls are the way to go.

Split your script into a single page download (like you proposed, `download.php?id=X`).

From the "main" script get the list from the database, iterate over it and send an ajax call to the script for each one. As all the calls will be fired all at once, check for your bandwidth and CPU time. You could break it into "X active task" using the success callback.

You can either set the `download.php` file to return success data or to save it to a database with the id of the website and the result of the call. I recommend the later because you can then just leave the main script and grab the results at a later time.

You can't increase the time limit indefinitively and can't wait indefinitively time to complete the request, so you need a "fire and forget" and that's what asynchronous call does best.

As @apokryfos pointed out, depending on the timing of this sort of "backups" you could fit this into a task scheduler (like chron). If you call it "on demand", put it in a gui, if you call it "every x time" put a chron task pointing the main script, it will do the same.

Comment: This request feels more like something that fits in a task scheduler and not in a client-side UI. CLI is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like a job for the console. The browser is for the users to see, but your task is something that the programmer will run, so use the console. Or schedule the file to run with a cron-job or anything similar that is handled by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Execute all the requests simultaneously using stream_socket_client(). Save all the socket IDs in an array

Then loop through the array of IDs with stream_select() to read the responses.

It's almost like multi-tasking within PHP.